# PHP Replace and Lowercase

Tags: php, replace

I am trying to do a PHP replace like ASP Replace. The function just returns a blank value though?

```
    $zonename=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["zonename"]);
    $zname_clean =""; # blank string
    $zname_clean = $zonename; # fill string with the post form
    $zname_clean = str_replace($zname_clean, " ", ""); # remove white space
```

That is my code. Example Zonename would be "Header Left", I want to remove capitalization and also remove whitespace.

How can I remove whitespace and convert the case and also is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Wrong parameter order -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
// strip out all whitespace
$zname_clean = preg_replace('/\s*/', '', $zname_clean);
// convert the string to all lowercase
$zname_clean = strtolower($zname_clean);
```

See the PHP manual for [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) and [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: The regex here is wrong. It should be /\s?/ -- The asterisk indicates "match zero or more times", what's needed is the question mark to match "one or more times".

Comment: No, the regex is fine. I want to remove all whitespace as per the question not just the first chat leaving further whitespace values.

Answer (score 6):

You have your parameters in the wrong order. Take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

It should be `str_replace(" ", "", $zname_clean);`

Another way of doing this is `strtolower(trim($zname_clean));`

Comment: not sure on your "Another way" - trim wont remove white space from the middle of the string

Comment: Your code will not remove all whitespace. What about line returns etc.

Comment: White space (space without meaning) or all spaces?

Answer (score 6):

Try this .

```
$zonename=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["zonename"]);
$zname_clean = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "",$zonename));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using String Replace Function

```
$zname_clean =  strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $zname_clean));
```

Using preg_replace

```
$zname_clean =  strtolower(preg_replace('/\s*/', '', $zname_clean));
```